# Vagrant 'paver devstack lms' Starting server: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: django, git, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm trying to install a devstack edx and I'm having some problems. I found this post

[How to fix python requirements update error (master branch) - SSO feature merged](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/edx-code/Command$20%22python$20setup.py$20egg_info%22$20failed$20with$20error$20code$201$20in/edx-code/FPfScH93R6M/5nvkOgolmvcJ)

But didn't work for me.
When I try to start the server I get the next fail:

```
dxapp@precise64:~/edx-platform$ paver devstack studio
---> pavelib.servers.devstack
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_ruby_prereqs
Ruby prereqs unchanged, skipping...
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
Node prereqs unchanged, skipping...
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_python_prereqs
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/pre.txt
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/github.txt
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Could not find a tag or branch '96e1922348bfe6d99201b9512a9ed946c87b7e0b', assuming commit.
Could not find a tag or branch 'b0686a76f1ce3532088c4aee6e76b9abe61cc808', assuming commit.
Could not find a tag or branch 'd89aae2a82f2b', assuming commit.
[... more lines with the same content ....]
Could not find a tag or branch 'a286e89c73e1b788e35ac5b08a54b71a9fa63cfd', assuming commit.
Could not find a tag or branch '64a8b603f42669bb7fdca03d364d4e8d3d6ad67d', assuming commit.
Could not find a tag or branch '172a90fd2738f8142c10478356b2d9ed3e55334a', assuming commit.
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/local.txt
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/base.txt
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
meliae is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
Requested meliae==0.4.0 (from -r requirements/edx/base.txt (line 53)), but installing version None
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rNPjSe/dm.xmlsec.binding`<br>


Captured Task Output:
---------------------

---> pavelib.servers.devstack
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_ruby_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_python_prereqs
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/pre.txt
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/github.txt
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/local.txt
pip install -q --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/base.txt

Build failed running pavelib.servers.devstack: Subprocess return code:1
```

By the way, I've already try to update pip, it looks like everything is ok (Successfully installed pip-7.1.0), but I always get that message when try the paver devstack studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this problem with some steps:

```
Requested meliae==0.4.0 (from -r requirements/edx/base.txt (line 53)),but installing version None
```

This line define there is **some error in `base.txt` file when vagrant try to install all base.txt file dependences.**

Solve this in steps:

1) Open `base.txt` file and comment `meliae==0.4.0` line like (`#meliae==0.4.0`)

2) Now try `pip install -r base.txt` file if it successfully run then no problem or if any other package create problem then follow 1(comment this for now) step.

3) after successfully run `base.txt`
   3.1) `exit` from `edx-platform`
   3.2) On vagrant instance (comes after `vagrant ssh` command) install all  commented packages (`pip install meliae==0.4.0` in my case)

NOW run your lms system again :)

Answer (score 1):

if the above steps don't work, try installing Cython, meliae==0.4.0, and libxmlsec1 from Vagrant instance.